# criar uma tela MDI com Python e PyQT5

Tags: python, pyqt-5

Estou fazendo um sistema com Python e PyQT5.
Já criei os menus e agora estou aplicando as funções necessárias de cada item.

Quero trabalhar com telas MDI e estou tendo dificuldades com isso.

Estou trabalhando com estrutura de pastas separadas para cada módulo e suas classes.

Quando eu crio meu script para criar a tela MDI tudo em um único script, sem separar as classes, funciona, cria a tela certinho, mas quando tendo fazer isso para o meu script principal não está funcionando, acredito que por causa das dependências, não sei.

Alguém poderia me ajudar a ajustar meu código para funcionar perfeitamente a criação da tela de "Criar SCD"?

"main"

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys
import lib.mainMenu as Menu
import lib.mainToolBar as MainToolbar

from lib.config import path_file
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QMessageBox, QMdiArea
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5 import QtGui

__version__ = "1.0.0"

image_root = path_file()
window_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\etl.png"

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1200, 800))
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(window_icon))
        self.title = 'System Converter Database - Version: '
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title + __version__)
        self.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())

        # Criando o Widget central
        self.mdi_area = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi_area)

        Menu.create_main_menu(self)
        MainToolbar.create_toolbar(self)

        self.statusBar().showMessage('Ready')

        self.show()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        quit_msg = "Deseja mesmo sair do sistema?"
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Saindo do sistema", quit_msg, QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

"modulo de menus"

```
# coding: utf-8

from lib.config import path_file
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QMessageBox, qApp, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize


image_root = path_file()


class MdiChild(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


def create_main_menu(handle):
    # Action do menu Criar SCD
    criar_scd_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\Criar_scd.png"
    action_criar_scd = QAction(QIcon(criar_scd_icon), "C&riar SCD", handle)
    action_criar_scd.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+R")
    action_criar_scd.triggered.connect(criar_scd)

    # Action do menu Localizar SCD
    localizar_scd_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\localizar.png"
    action_localizar_scd = QAction(QIcon(localizar_scd_icon), "&Localizar SCD", handle)
    action_localizar_scd.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+L")
    action_localizar_scd.triggered.connect(localizar_scd)

    # Action do menu Conversor/passo a passo/copiar
    copiar_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\copiar.png"
    action_copiar = QAction(QIcon(copiar_icon), "&Copiar", handle)
    action_copiar.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+C")
    action_copiar.triggered.connect(copiar)

    # Action do menu Conversor/passo a passo/extrair
    extrair_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\extrair.png"
    action_extrair = QAction(QIcon(extrair_icon), "&Extrair", handle)
    action_extrair.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+E")
    action_extrair.triggered.connect(extrair)

    # Action do menu Conversor/passo a passo/Preparar
    preparar_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\preparar.png"
    action_preparar = QAction(QIcon(preparar_icon), "&Preparar", handle)
    action_preparar.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+P")
    action_preparar.triggered.connect(preparar)

    # Action do menu Conversor/passo a passo/converter
    converter_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\converter.png"
    action_converter = QAction(QIcon(converter_icon), "Co&nverter", handle)
    action_converter.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+N")
    action_converter.triggered.connect(converter)

    # Action do menu Conversor/automático/iniciar
    automatico_iniciar_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\automatico.png"
    action_automatico_iniciar = QAction(QIcon(automatico_iniciar_icon), "&Iniciar", handle)
    action_automatico_iniciar.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+I")
    action_automatico_iniciar.triggered.connect(automatico_iniciar)

    # Action do menu Verificador/iniciar
    verificador_iniciar_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\automatico.png"
    action_verificador_iniciar = QAction(QIcon(verificador_iniciar_icon), "Veri&ficador", handle)
    action_verificador_iniciar.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+F")
    action_verificador_iniciar.triggered.connect(verificador_iniciar)

    # Action do menu sair
    sair_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\exit.png"
    action_sair = QAction(QIcon(sair_icon), "&Sair", handle)
    action_sair.setShortcut("Ctrl+Shift+S")
    action_sair.triggered.connect(sair)

    # Criando barra de menu principal
    main_menu = handle.menuBar()
    menu_scd = main_menu.addMenu("SC&D")
    menu_converter = main_menu.addMenu("C&onversor")
    menu_converter_automatico = menu_converter.addMenu("&Automático")
    menu_converter_passo = menu_converter.addMenu("&Passo a passo")
    menu_verificador = main_menu.addMenu("&Verificador")
    menu_sair = main_menu.addMenu("&Sair")

    # Criando os sub-menus
    menu_scd.addAction(action_criar_scd)
    menu_scd.addAction(action_localizar_scd)
    menu_sair.addAction(action_sair)
    menu_converter_passo.addAction(action_copiar)
    menu_converter_passo.addAction(action_extrair)
    menu_converter_passo.addAction(action_preparar)
    menu_converter_passo.addAction(action_converter)
    menu_converter_automatico.addAction(action_automatico_iniciar)
    menu_verificador.addAction(action_verificador_iniciar)


def create_mdi_child(parent=None):
    if parent is not None:
        child = MdiChild()
        parent.mdi_area.addSubWindow(child)

        return child


def criar_scd(parent=None):
    tela_scd = parent.create_mdi_child()
    tela_scd.setWindowTitle("Criar SCD")
    tela_scd.setMinimumSize(QSize(1200, 800))
    tela_scd.show()

    print("Criar SCD")


def localizar_scd():
    print("Localizar SCD")


def copiar():
    pass


def extrair():
    pass


def preparar():
    pass


def converter():
    pass


def automatico_iniciar():
    pass


def verificador_iniciar():
    pass


def sair():
    box_quit = QMessageBox()
    box_quit.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(image_root + r"\public\icons\etl.png"))
    box_quit.setIcon(QMessageBox.Question)
    box_quit.setWindowTitle("Saindo do sistema")
    box_quit.setText("Deseja mesmo sair do sistema?")
    box_quit.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
    box_quit.setDefaultButton(QMessageBox.No)

    reply = box_quit.exec_()
    if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
        qApp.quit()
```

Quando clico no menu "Criar SCD" o sistema não cria a tela MDI que deveria ser criada e fecha o sistema.

Preciso de ajuda para fazer aparecer essa tela MDI, por favor.

Se eu faço desse jeito abaixo, dá certo, ele cria a janela MDI com sucesso, mas não sei como fazer para adaptar isso a minha realidade.

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget))

        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.layout().addWidget(self.mdiArea)

        subWindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow(self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("close", widget) 
        widget.layout().addWidget(btn)

        btn.clicked.connect(subWindow.close)

        subWindow.setWidget(widget)
        subWindow.setObjectName("New_Window")
        subWindow.setWindowTitle("New SubWindow")
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWindow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Alguém tem alguma idéias de como resolver essa situação?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema mencionado acima.
Vou postar aqui como eu consegui fazer o que eu queria.
Toda a parte é feita no modulo view importado abaixo:

```
from view.view_main import MainWindow
```

"main"

```
class AppMainWindow(MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, ):
        super(AppMainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.move(app.desktop().screen().rect().center() - self.rect().center())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = AppMainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

"Modulo View"

```
# coding: utf-8

import sys

from lib.config import path_file
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMdiArea, QMessageBox, QAction, QMdiSubWindow, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QKeySequence

__version__ = "1.0.0"

image_root = path_file()
window_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\etl.png"


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    child_count = 0

    def __init__(self, ):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setMinimumSize(QSize(1200, 800))
        self.title = 'System Converter Database - Version: '
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(window_icon))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title + __version__)

        #Criando o widget central
        self.mdi_widget = QMdiArea()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.mdi_widget)

        self.create_actions_menu()
        self.create_main_menu()


    def closeEvent(self, event):
        quit_msg = "Deseja mesmo sair do sistema?"
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, "Saindo do sistema", quit_msg, QMessageBox.Yes, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    def create_main_menu(self):
        main_menu = self.menuBar()  # Barra de Menus
        self.menu_scd = main_menu.addMenu("&SCD")  # Menu SCD
        self.menu_scd.addAction(self.action_create_scd)  # SubMenu "Criar SCD"
        self.menu_scd.addAction(self.action_search_scd)


    def create_actions_menu(self):
        # Ação para Menu "Criar SCD"
        create_scd_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\Criar_scd.png"
        self.action_create_scd = QAction(QIcon(create_scd_icon), "&Criar", self,
                                         shortcut=QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+C"),
                                         triggered=self.create_scd)
        # Ação para Menu "Localizar SCD"
        search_scd_icon = image_root + r"\public\icons\localizar.png"
        self.action_search_scd = QAction(QIcon(search_scd_icon), "&Localizar", self,
                                         shortcut=QKeySequence("Ctrl+Shift+L"),
                                         triggered=self.search_scd)

    def create_scd(self):
        self.create_child_window()
        print("Criar SCD")

    def search_scd(self):
        print("Localizar SCD")

    def create_child_window(self):
        sub = QMdiSubWindow()
        sub.setWidget(QWidget())
        sub.setWindowTitle("teste")
        self.mdi_widget.addSubWindow(sub)
        sub.show()
```

O pulo do gato ficou por conta do bloco de código abaixo:

```
def create_child_window(self):
            sub = QMdiSubWindow()
            sub.setWidget(QWidget())
            sub.setWindowTitle("teste")
            self.mdi_widget.addSubWindow(sub)
            sub.show()
```

Acontece que antes, na pergunta acima eu não estava conseguindo, pois eu não estava conseguindo instanciar, ou fazer herdar de um objeto tipo QWindow.

Obrigado por todas as visualizações e tentativas de ajuda. Agora é só eu aprimorar.